# how do you make a razor view extension method in asp.net core?

Tags: asp.net-core, razor, asp.net-core-mvc

i wan't to be able to call "this.Method()" inside a razor editor template.

i used to be able to do this in MVC5 using an extension method with the following signature:

```
public static T SomeMethod<T>(this WebViewPage page) {

}
```

but in asp.net core razor views aren't "WebViewPage" anymore.

i've tried this but it didn't work:

```
public static T SomeMethod<T>(this RazorPage<T> page) {

}
```

the error is this:

> Error CS1929  'Areas_puck_Views_Shared_EditorTemplates_PuckImagePicker' does not contain a definition for 'SomeMethod' and the best extension method overload  'ViewExtensions.SomeMethod
>   (RazorPage`<PuckImagePickerEditorSettings>`)' requires a receiver of type 
>   'RazorPage`<PuckImagePickerEditorSettings>`'

Comment: In what namespace does `RazorPage` live? Do your extension method and your page use the same one?

Comment: the namespace the extension method is using is Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorPage. i don't know how to check what the view is using, i assumed it was the same

Answer (score 2, accepted):

problem solved by changing the extension method signature to this:

```
public static T SomeMethod<T>(this RazorPageBase page) {

}
```

`RazorPageBase` is in the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor` namespace. now i can call `SomeMethod` from my razor editor template: `this.SomeMethod()`.

of course i've also added a using statement in `_ViewImports.cshtml` to include the extension method.

thanks